# Script to start computer in Safe Mode and then restart it in Normal Mode?

Tags: windows-7, script, shell-script

My PC has Windows 7 and over time it refuses to go beyond the Windows logo animation unless I start it up in safe mode first, and then restart in normal mode.

That's quite a chore to do everyday and if I miss hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> at the right moment I have to hard-boot the computer and start again. Is there a script that can automate this?

Comment: can you provide the specification of your machine, which would make things more clearer

Comment: Just wondering if you'd got to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Andrew nope, the problem still persists

Answer (score 3):

Surely the first thing you should be doing is determining why this odd behaviour happens.

PCs don't (as a rule) have sentient thinking... clearly something is hanging, and whilst rebooting via safe mode may be unblocking it, the behaviour suggests an underlying problem.

But to (not)answer the question, you seem to be wanting a Windows equivalent to the Linux init() command. I'm sure someone will be along with the syntax, if such a beastie exists.

Comment: i wish i could figure out the problem, i suspect my new graphics card but i've tried updating its drivers, even reinstalling my computer then i just gave up. now i just want a workaround till i can solve this problem

Comment: Yes, check the event log.  If you lack the mad skilz to determine the problem, find someone who has them.  Don't try and band-aid over the root issue with a hack.